# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

My Controller function

```
use App\Tag

public function index()
{
    //
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('tags.index')->withTags('$tags');
}
```

Index view blade

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
<tr>
<th>{{ $tag->id }}</th>
<td>
<a href="{{route('tags.show', $tag->id)}}">{{ $tag- >name }}</a>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `'$tags'` would be a literal `$tags`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the single quotes and `Tags` in `withTags('$tags')` so it becomes:

```
public function index()
{
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('tags.index')->with('tags', $tags);
}
```

or you could use `compact` and do what Salman said.

Answer (score 3):

use **compact** it's easier and simpler try the below code:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('tags.index',compact('tags'));
}
```

if you want to use **with** then try below code:

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('tags.index')->with('tags',$tags);
    }
```

in blade you can do what you are doing or you can use **forelse** try the below code:

```
@forelse($tags as $tag)
<tr>
<th>{{ $tag->id }}</th>
<td>
<a href="{{route('tags.show', $tag->id)}}">{{ $tag- >name }}</a>
</td>
</tr>
@empty
<div class='alert alert-danger'>
  No tags..!
</div>
@endforelse
```